# Google Maps center view from other VARIABLE

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, maps

So this is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC-dbN2gdvXsx09jfJHmNc8"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {


var customIcons = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {       
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.289796, 106.822370),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      //^ HOW TO GET CENTER VALUE FROM VAR POINT IN FUNCTION LOAD() ???? ^ //
var markarray=[]
    function load() {

           for (var i = 0; i < markarray.length; i++) {
             markarray[i].setMap(null);
             } 
            markarray = [];
      console.log("ok")
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("http://localhost/maps6/genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          //var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var date_taken = markers[i].getAttribute("date_taken");
          //var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                  //^ HOW TO GET THE POINT VALUE TO CENTER IN VAR MAP ???? ^ //
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + date_taken;
          var icon = 'mark.png';
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: 'mark.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          markarray.push(marker);
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    $("#BtnClicked").live('click',function(){load();});


  setInterval(function() {load();},3000);

});

 //]]>
  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 1280px; height: 720px"></div>
    <a href="#" id="BtnClicked">test</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When code is executed, the result is:
[image: RESULT IMAGE in IMGUR]

^ The green marker is automatic update their position based on MYSQL Database without reloading the entire Google Maps page

So my question is **how to get Google MAPS CENTER (in var map) from VAR POINT in function load()**

Comment: Are you asking how to center the map on the marker?  Or how to get the existing center of the map?  If you want to center the map on the marker, call `map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());` when you create the marker.

Comment: Yeah I'm just want to center the map on the marker.
Thanks man it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to geocodezip turns out to solve this problem is just add `map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());` after

```
markarray.push(marker);
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
```